# mark line doesn't work whereas mark circle works

Tags: vega-lite

I would like to draw a line chart for a field `raw_value` and I've this code :

```
{
  $schema: https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json
  data: {
    url: {
      %context%: true
      %timefield%: @timestamp
      index: filebeat-*
      body: {
        size: 10000
        _source: ["@timestamp","raw_value"]
      }
    }
    format: {property: "hits.hits"}
  }
  transform: [
    {calculate: "toDate(datum._source['@timestamp'])", as: "time"}
  ]

  mark: circle
  encoding: {
    x: {field: "time", type: "temporal"}
    y: {field: "_source.raw_value", type: "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

it works well and I see the circles for each couple (`time`,`raw_value`), but if i want to draw a line to rely points and i replace `circle` by `line`, nothing appears on the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines are only drawn between adjacent non-null points, so what you describe generally means that you have null `y` values in your data. You can fix this by filtering out undefined data before drawing your lines:

```
  transform: [
    {calculate: "toDate(datum._source['@timestamp'])", as: "time"},
    {filter: "isDefined(datum._source.raw_value)"}
  ]
```

Comment: thanks !  any chance you know a link for a doc to learn things like this about vega ?